# Simple map function call in nodejs async library not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Recently I discovered [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library and wanted to try it. The information provided for getting started is quite simple. So I decided to try an example. I tried it, the call reaches the iterator function but never reaches the callback. Could someone advise?

```js
var async = require('async')

// My simple iterator
function foo(item){
    console.log('foo');
    return item;
}

// And this is my simple try out
async.mapLimit(inputData,100,foo,function(err, result){
    console.log(err, result, 'Finished');
});
```

Comment: @caolan, Please advise....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

foo should be

```
function foo(item, callback){
   console.log('foo');
   callback(null, item); // or actually do something to item
}
```